# Get Vive Cosmos' proximity sensor state

Tags: unity, c#, virtual-reality

I'm working on a project with both VR and Desktop modes in the same scene and using *Ultraleap*.
I was previously using an *HTC Vive* and *SteamVR* to detect if the user put the headset on his head with the headset's proximity sensor.

I'm now switching to *Vive Cosmos* and *OpenXR* and I don't use the *SteamVR* plugin anymore. I get the information if the headset is mounted on the user's head with XRSupportUtil from *Ultraleap*.
`XRSupportUtil.IsUserPresent()`
(It does approximately the same thing as `InputDevices.GetDeviceAtXRNode(UnityEngine.XR.XRNode.Head).TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.userPresence, out bool isUserPresent);`).

The problem is that the *Vive Cosmos* doesn't give the information the same way as *HTC Vive* does. It switches on the user's presence only when the headset is moving and switches it off when the headset isn't moving for like 15s.

I'd like to know if there is a way to get the *Vive Cosmos*' proximity sensor state instead of tracking the user's presence. Or at least bypass having to wait so long before to switch to VR off.